# Webrtc Media Server Components

Tags: server, video-streaming, webrtc, media, video-conferencing

It's been a while since I started learning WebRTC and after a lot of research I'm still not able to get what are the components of a Media Server when used. I know that there are many open source projects on GitHub and many vendors are actually selling it commercially but what I'm interested in is the total components which it is made of.

***What I know :***

1)Media Server is required when you have 1000+clients as it requires a server to manage all the streams.

2) SFU and MCU are part of the Media Server. (NOTE: YES, I'm aware of the terms SFU and MCU).

***What I'm eager to Know is :**

The architecture of the Media Server with its component's or layout if any. And am I correct when it comes to the things which I mentioned ***What I know :***

**PS:** I have done a lot of homework before asking this question and was unable to get an clear picture of the same.

Comment: What are you asking about, specifically?  The server-side components can be whatever you need them to be.

Comment: can you give me an example of what components resides in media server.